# Sumproduct with array condition

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I would like to use one sumproduct formula that relies on an array of conditions of cellvalue. So basically I want to sum something when one of the entries of some cells where found before.

I can make the array of conditions work but not by cell values. In example.

```
Let A1 = "a", A2 = "b", B1 = 1, B2 = 2
```

Then

```
C1 = Sumproduct((A1:A100={"a"."b"})*(B1:B100)) = 3
```

works fine, but

```
C2 = Sumproduct((A1:A100=A1:A2)*(B1:B100)) = ERROR
```

Is there any way to put {"a"."b"} into a cell or an set of cells?

Greetings and Thanks for your help,
Peter

Disclaimer: I know I could simply write:

```
C2 = Sumproduct((A1:A100=A1)*(B1:B100)) + Sumproduct((A1:A100=A2)*(B1:B100))
```

But I would like to have a solution that is still nice to handle if 10+ conditions are on the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TRANSPOSE to make the cyclic calculation think of A1:A2 as being in a different order (... *direction*?) than A1:A100 and B1:B100.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100=TRANSPOSE(A1:A2))*(B1:B100))
```

This formula is a true array formula and requires CSE.

Comment: Thank you, both answers work fine for me. My Personal favorite is Jeepeds one.

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNTIF:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A2,A1:A100)*B1:B100)
```

Comment: This solution works for me. If you're looking to have your {"a"."b"} in a cell or a range somewhere, you can do that. Just replace `A1:A2` in @tigeravatar's formula above with the range you end up using for your designated values.